# UI is not updating after record is deleted in GraphQl typescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typescript, graphql, relayjs

Im using Graphql in rails. When I delete a Bicycle it doesn't update in UI I have to refresh my page in order to make the Bicycle go.
This is my Query:

```
const [commitDelete, isInFlight] = useMutation<DeleteBicycleMutation>(
      graphql`
          mutation BicycleListDeleteBicycleMutation($input: DeleteBicycleMutationInput!) {
              deleteBicycle(input: $input) {
                  bicycle {
                      id
                  },
              }
          }
      `
  );
```

This is handle click function:

```
  const handleDeleteClick = (bicycle: BicycleRow_bicycle$data, connectionsID: string) => {
      commitDelete({
          variables: {
              input: {
                  id: bicycle.id,
              },
            
          },
          onCompleted: (response, errors) => {
              console.log("Completed");
          },
          onError: (error) => {
              // handle error
          },
      });
  };
```

This is DeleteBicycleMutation.graphql.ts:

```
import { ConcreteRequest } from "relay-runtime"
import { FragmentRefs } from "relay-runtime"
export type DeleteBicycleMutationInput = {
    brand?: string | null
    clientMutationId?: string | null
    id: string
    model?: string | null
    quantity?: number | null
    sizeCentimeters?: number | null
}
export type DeleteBicycleMutationVariables = {
    // connections: ReadonlyArray<string>;
    input: DeleteBicycleMutationInput
}
export type DeleteBicycleMutationResponse = {
    readonly deleteBicycle: {
      readonly deletedBicycleId: string | null
    } | null
}
export type DeleteBicycleMutation = {
    readonly variables: DeleteBicycleMutationVariables
    readonly response: DeleteBicycleMutationResponse
}
```

I Tried to delete a bicycle, it got deleted but the UI is not updating.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

In deletion cases you need to `refetch` the query that generated your page. Depending on your GraphQL client this can be done as part of the mutation or in your `onCompleted` handler.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue, the issue was in the Query I wrote.
Correct query should be:

```
    const [commitDelete, isInFlight] = useMutation<BicycleList_DeleteBicycleMutation>(
        graphql`
          mutation BicycleList_DeleteBicycleMutation($connections: [ID!]!, $input: 
    DeleteBicycleMutationInput!) {
            deleteBicycle(input: $input) {
              bicycle  {
                id @deleteEdge(connections: $connections)
              },
            }
          }
        `,
      );
```